# $S_k \triangleq \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^k$ implies $p | S_k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Here is a small cute lemma, that I have encountered while solving a problem. Hope you will enjoy it.

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Define $S_k$ via
$$
S_k \triangleq \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^k.
$$
Show that $p \mid S_k$ for all $1 \leq k < p-1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the equal sign with the birthday hat? I've never seen it before. Also, Happy Birthday equal sign!

Comment: What do you mean by $ \triangleq$?

Comment: I think it means define $S_k$ to be that sum.

Comment: Does it mean "is defined as being equal to"?

Comment: You're better off telling us what you've done to show that yourself. You might get close votes otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different proof from the links shown. Hope this is correct.

If $k$ is odd, then $i^k + (p-i)^k = 0 \mod p$

Consider $k$ even:

$1^k, 2^k, ..., (p-1)^k$ are all quadratic residues$\mod p$ with the values being equal WLOG to $1, g, g^2, ..., g^{(p-3)/2}$ and whose sum is $g^{(p-1)/2} - 1$ which is $0 \mod p$ per Fermat and where $g$ is a quadratic residue.